# SQL Where Clause Not Returning Correct Results

Tags: sql, where-clause

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[_5200_Sanoma] 
WHERE right(left([VARIABLE1)],4),2) = 'RI' 
and (
        ([Year] = '2014' and [Period] in('10','11','12'))
        or [Year] = '2015') 
        or  (
                [Year] = '2016' 
                and [Period] in('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08')--,'09','10','11','12')
            )
and ([VARIABLE2] IN(
'String1',
'String2',
'String3',
'String4',
'String5',
'String6',
))
```

I had to change a few things to be more general but for some reason the first where clause, the `right(left([VARIABLE1)],4),2) = 'RI'` isn't working because I'm getting back results where that is other two character strings.

This query has worked before I added the last where clause condition

```
   and ([VARIABLE2] IN(
    'String1',
    'String2',
    'String3',
    'String4',
    'String5',
    'String6',
    ))
```

So now that I added that it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to split your statements in different lines; you probably meant to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[_5200_Sanoma] 
WHERE right(left([VARIABLE1)],4),2) = 'RI' AND
(
    ([Year] = '2014' and [Period] in('10','11','12')) OR
    ([Year] = '2015') OR
    ([Year] = '2016' and [Period] in('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08'))
)
and ([VARIABLE2] IN ('String1','String2','String3','String4','String5','String6'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you just have some parenthesis problems with your or clauses (One of them is not included in the `AND` part after `WHERE right(left([VARIABLE1)],4),2) = 'RI'`

Try

```
    and (
            ([Year] = '2014' and [Period] in('10','11','12')) or 
             [Year] = '2015' or  
            ([Year] = '2016' and [Period] in('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08')--,'09','10','11','12')
        )
```